# Using Visual Studio 2010 for Sharepoint 2010 development

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am a newbie to SharePoint 2010 development, even though am a .net developer for past 3 years. I have setup development env with windows 7(64-bit), sharepoint foundation 2010, visual studio 2010, and sql server 2001 R2 in a virtual machine. As a beginning, I created a new web application in SharePoint 2010 and also created new site collection. Then I created a custom list for student details. Now I need to create a simple student registration page which validate all the user entries for example email id, phone number etc using regular expression and few fields using required field validator.  I need to how can I use Visual Studio 2010 for this purpose. Please consider this as an entry level question in SharePoint 2010 development. Hope this question fits right in this forum.

Comment: you could develop your application in asp.net and set it up properly in iss then just extend the application to sharepoint. I am also new to sharepoint development but coming from a few years of asp.net as well i found this the easiest. for validation since the application will be extended - do it the same way you would for an application not using sharepoint (javascript/whatever you prefer for field validators)

Answer (score 1):

Start the Visual studio
File  Menu-> New -> Project -> Select SharePoint From installed Template -> Empty SharePoint Project 
Give proper name and save it

then it ask for **SharePoint URL**

enter **SharePoint URL** and validate it then press **Finish** button

Now your solution is ready to use

in solution explorer select project right click on it
Add new Item -> Visual web part 
you have to write your code in User control on this web part some code snippet is as follow:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList StudentInfoList = web.Lists["Student Information"];
        SPListItemCollection listItems = StudentInfoList.GetItems();
        SPListItem item = listItems.Add();
        item["RollNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);;
        item["StudentName"] = TextBox2.Text
        item["PhoneNumber"] = TextBox3.Text;
        item["EmailID"] = TextBox4.Text;
        item.Update();
        StudentInfoList.Update();
    }
}
```

Welcome to SharePoint :-)